# Xamarin UITest (Calabash) Query for Non-Empty text Property

Tags: c#, calabash, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

In Xamarin UITest (which uses Calabash) I can query an element that has `some text`, like so:

```
app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("MyTextControl")
                   .Property("text")
                   .Contains("some text"));
```

I see in the [reference docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/calabash-query-syntax/#Predicate) that there is also BEGINSWITH, LIKE, and so on, but I don't see any sort of IsEmpty or IsNotEmpty. Is there a way to find an element with text that is not empty? I was expecting to see a Length method, so I could do something like:

```
app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("MyTextControl")
                   .Property("text")
                   .Length() > 0);
```

Is there another way to accomplish what I am after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the specific question, I do not believe it is possible to accomplish this within a specific Query in the UITest API's. The best workaround would be to what @Zil suggested and to query for all elements of a specific Identifier and then loop over them to find what you are looking for, or something similar to that idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it like so, for `UILabels`. I don't think it works for `UIButtons`, for buttons you have to dig a bit deeper in the `AppResult[]`, but it should be doable alone, I've just never had the chance to have text in my buttons when I did UITests.

```
AppResult[] labelContainer = app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("MyTextControl");
AppResult label = labelContainer[0];
```

You always have at least one element in the array, otherwise the `WaitForElement` fails. So no risk of out-of-bounds here.

Now we're making sure there is text, that should be answering your question specifically.

```
Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(label.Text));
```

If you wanna be thourough you can apply the next line in a  `for loop` to test each element of the given array of items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < labelContainer.Length ; i++)
{
    AppResult label = labelContainer[i];
    Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(label.Text)); 
}
```

Of course  you could make an extension method that does all this for a given Mark, or one-line it like so :

```
  Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("MyTextControl")[0].Text));
```

And with all this you should be a happy man for the next few minutes :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this approach is useful when you want to assert that all elements with a given identifier are non-empty, but cannot easily be used when you want to query to find _only_ elements with a given identifier that are non-empty, or when you want to wait until an element with a given identifier _becomes_ non-empty. (I need to do the latter.) I could hack it with a loop, `Thread.Sleep` and a custom timeout, but that is more of a workaround. Seems like something that should be possible with the Calabash query itself.

Comment: > I don't think it works for UIButtons

The text property will be the title (if any) of the button.

Comment: @Zil I recommend updating the first example to this: `AppResult label = labelContainer?.FirstOrDefault();`, because using `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if the array is empty whereas referencing index 0, `[0]`, will throw a `NullReferenceException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception if the array is empty. I've found this helpful because sometimes the element doesn't appear on the screen. Here's a sample I have in GitHub: https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/blob/master/UITestSampleApp/UITestSampleApp.UITests/Pages/ListPage.cs#L40

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just simply do like that:

```
app.WaitForElement(x => x.Marked("MyTextControl")
                         .Property("text")
                         .Like(*));
```

If you want to get not null text elements!

I tried but I'm not sure it's correct for all cases or not! If you find some problem with my answer, please fix me! Thanks a lot! :D